# Rights to create users in only one SQL Database

Tags: sql-server

Restating my question: I have an SQL server for a client that has development and production databases on it. The client wants their admin to be able to create users and logins to one of the databases, but not give their admin ability to give users access to the other database.  I realize that users are created at the database level and logins at the server level, so am not sure what permissions this would mean the admin have to have.  How can they create logins (sql server admin?)yet only be able to create users in one database?

Comment: Logins are not at the database level. They are at the server level and may or may not have access to a given database. Not really sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Depends what they want those Users for. IF you mean so that they can connect to SQL Server, then the `USER` will need a `LOGIN` that it is mapped to; or the database will need to be a contained database so that a `USER` can connect the database directly. [Contained Database Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: If, of course, they want to simply create the users without a login, to test permissions, they they would be able to fulfil their need with simply the ability to create a `USER` within the context of the database.